# Пароль на Телеграм бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

```py
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'Check' and message.text == "1234введите сюда код":
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Вы Вошли', parse_mode="Markdown")
```

Я знаю что `callback` не может считывать сообщения, тогда как сделать, я пытался `callback_inline(call, message)` делать, увы, я обычно писал код на Lua, тут пайтон, буду благодарен за объяснение

Comment: Вопрос решен) я нашел ответ, только вот как сделать так что бы это сохранялось, тип я пароль ввел и даже если юзер перезапустит бот, он уже будет в аккаунте

Comment: Сделай либо бд, либо можешь хранить список авторизованных пользователей просто в каком-то json и при запуске читать от туда этот список.